# Check if object has function defined using a string variable

Tags: javascript

Given following code, I want to check if `someObject` has `bar` function using the variable `fn`.

```
var SomeObject = function() {};

SomeObject.prototype.foo = function() {
   var fn = 'bar';

   // todo: I want to check if this object has 'bar' function.
   // if yes call it

   // Note: you can't do if(typeof this.bar === 'function')
   // got to use the variable fn
};

var OtherObject = function() {
    SomeObject.call(this);
};

OtherObject.prototype = Object.create(SomeObject.prototype);

OtherObject.prototype.bar = function() {
    console.log('great. I was just called.');
};

var obj = new OtherObject();
obj.foo();
```

Comment: `this[fn]();` + `fn in this` + `typeof this[fn]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (typeof this[fn] === 'function') {
    this[fn]();
}
```

Comment: @Subash - how so? I just tried it. works just fine.
instead of saying it's wrong, explain what is wrong about it. I satisfied the requirements you gave. If that is incorrect, you should address that.